# How to apply a style to all Controls of the same type?

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, controls

How to apply a style to all Controls of the same type (Buttons for example)?
without specifying the style every time Control declared in XAML.
Ie I want to specify the style once for all the buttons.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just put it without key

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you.
It works for the menu declared in XAML
But for menus created dynamically (from C #. CS code) style is not set.

Comment: Style I created in my dictionary.
The dictionary is connected to the control in XAML
    `<UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>`


If I try to create a button on the control of code in C# style is not installed.